# changing loudness with amixer

Tags: 20.04, sound, amixer

I want to set the loudness with amixer on my Ubuntu 20.04 system, Kernel 5.15. amixer prints the the "Simple mixer control 'PCM', 0" and "Simple mixer control 'IEC958', 0". But no master. When I set the loudness for PCM it does not change the actual loudness at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I use. I use Ubuntu Mate 18.04.

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 20%
```

Comment: thanks @fixit7 works fine